# SQL - combining filtered and non-filtered fields in SELECT

Tags: sql, sqlite

### my_table

```
id  model  datetime     driver   distance
---|-----|------------|--------|---------
1  | S   | 04/03/2009 | john   | 399 
2  | X   | 04/03/2009 | juliet | 244
3  | 3   | 04/03/2009 | borat  | 555
4  | 3   | 03/03/2009 | john   | 300
5  | X   | 03/03/2009 | juliet | 200
6  | X   | 03/03/2009 | borat  | 500
7  | S   | 24/12/2008 | borat  | 600
8  | X   | 01/01/2009 | borat  | 700
```

### required output

```
model  all_trips     driver   distance
-----|------------|--------|---------
  3  | 2          | borat  | 555
  X  | 4          | borat  | 1200
  S  | 2          | borat  | 600
```

### my query so far

```
SELECT
model AS model, driver AS driver
SUM(distance) as total_distance
FROM my_table
WHERE driver = 'borat'
GROUP BY model
```

### output

```
model  driver   total_distance
-----|--------|--------
 3   | borat  | 555
 X   | borat  | 1200
 S   | borat  | 600
```

I need help to get the `all_trips` column where all_trips refer to the unfiltered count of records per model (ie. without the filter `WHERE driver = 'borat'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Just needed to join on counts per each model.

```
select m.model,t.cnt as all_trips,m.distance,m.driver 
from (SELECT model,driver,SUM(distance) as distance
      FROM my_table
      WHERE driver = 'borat'
      GROUP BY model,driver) m
JOIN (select model,count(*) as cnt from my_table group by model) t  on t.model=m.model
```